# "/proc/net/dev" contains all zeroes

Tags: networking, 13.10, system-monitor

On my Ubuntu 13.10 desktop, the `/proc/net/dev` file contains only zeroes for all interfaces other than `lo`, despite having a working connection. This seems to lead most bandwidth monitoring tools to believe that there is no network traffic at all, including `gnome-system-monitor`.

Here's a screenshot of EtherApe, System Monitor and `/proc/net/dev` all together:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, EtherApe is recording about 1.16 Mbps in HTTPS traffic alone, while System Monitor says 0 bytes/s. Any ideas as to why this would happen, and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed the same problem on mint linux(debian), may work for you too.
`/proc/net/dev` was not populated (eth0 had `0`'es in stats for everything), as result everything that gets info from it like ifcongif: misses data and some apps like browsers and Adobe Flash was working a bit laggy.

I think problem was on misconfiguration of kernel compiled when i build(install) my system, so i simply used packet manager ('mintupdate', but ubuntu somehow can work with kernel updates too, i belive) to `update kernel` from 3.13.0-37 to 3.16.0-33.
And after reboot all problems are gone, youtube now can play hd videos without switching quality like crazy (144p->720p->360p->144p->720p lol)

Comment: As noted in [another question](http://askubuntu.com/a/425115) the bug that caused this was solved in Linux 3.14rc1, so updating the kernel past that will fix the issue.