# Network traffic reports as zero bytes

Tags: networking, statistical

Just installed Ubuntu Server 13.10. I'm in the middle of setting up some scripts that help me monitoring the server's activity. Now I find that the network traffic stays at zero bytes.

Here's what I mean: /proc/net/dev says:

```
@boson:~ $ cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
 p17p1:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo:    1184      16    0    0    0     0          0         0     1184      16    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

For those wondering:

```
@boson:~ $ lspci | grep Ethernet
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

.

```
@boson:~ $ uname -a
Linux boson 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

.

```
@boson:~ $ cat /sys/class/net/p17p1/statistics/*
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

.

```
@boson:~ $ netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
lo        65536 0        16      0      0 0            16      0      0      0 LRU
p17p1      1500 0         0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMRU
```

.

```
@boson:~ $ sudo lshw
:
    *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: p17p1
                version: 10
                serial: bc:5f:f4:ea:0e:28
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=10.0.1.220 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:51 memory:ff600000-ff63ffff ioport:e000(size=128)
:
```

The infamous `alx` module perhaps?

```
@boson:~ $ modinfo alx
filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.0-17-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
author:         Johannes Berg <johannes@sipsolutions.net>
srcversion:     B18081BDFB465ACD502D031
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.11.0-17-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Any clues on how to get the counters working is welcome.

Comment: Looking at this [link](https://wiki.debian.org/alx). Could it be possible that the `alx` module not yet fully supports the card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stats are back in 3.14rc1.

source : https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=63401

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. Can I just wait a while for that fix to get installed with `apt-get upgrade`? Or do I need to become more active?

Comment: I'm guessing the 3.12 kernel won't be with us until Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: [26APR2014] Just upgraded to the 14.04 LTS release. Unfortunately this has kernel version `3.13.0-24`. So no solution yet...

Comment: Same problem here with: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] and Ubuntu 14.04 kernel 3.13.0-30-generic

Comment: Same problem here with Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet and Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with kernel `modinfo alx | grep vermagic` giving `vermagic: 3.13.0-35-generic SMP mod_unload modversions`. Is there a fix yet?

What is strange btw, is that it was working just fine with `Ubuntu 12.04`. I could also 'wake up' my computer with wake on LAN via my modem. This is also not working anymore.

Comment: Same problem here with Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 and Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with kernel 3.13.0-43-generic SMP

Comment: [21DEC2014] Since upgrading to Ubuntu 14.10 the counters work.